# Backbone.js + MVC3. Nested collection doesn't get populated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection on the client.
Model of the collection has some properties along with another collection

When I do `fetch()` my action method on the server returns some data, collection gets populated, all the properties too, except that nested collection.

What could be the reason?

```
var Job = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Jobs = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Job})

var Foo = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    initialize:function(){
      this.jobs = new Jobs();
}})
var FooCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Foo})

var fooCol = new FooCollection()
fooCol.fetch();

fooCol.first().get('name') // => returns name
fooCol.first().jobs.toJSON() // returns nothing
// although this will
fooCol.first().get('jobs') //it will return an array
```

So somehow nested Backbone collection becomes just a regular property (Array)

Comment: What does your actual response look like? The `this.jobs = new Jobs` has nothing to do with `.get('jobs')` - looking at the code you've supplied, they aren't related at all.

Comment: alright I think the problem is that somehow MVC serializes collections straight into arrays... and backbone then recognizes those arrays, and somehow with inner collection that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - with your extra information, I can give you an answer.

First - "get" doesn't get a property off of the model. It gets a property off of the model's `attributes` property. So, the attributes probably look like:

```
{
    name: 'blah',
    jobs: [{name: 'job1'}, {name: 'job2'}]
}
```

Backbone doesn't automagically transform arrays into collections and models, and simply setting `this.jobs` isn't going to work. What you need to do is a little more complex.

```
var Foo = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    initialize:function(){
      this.jobs = new Jobs(this.attributes.jobs));
    }
});
```

This will set your 'jobs' property to a new jobs object with the data that was sent over for the jobs. But, alas, it won't automatically fire events on the Jobs collection, nor will it allow you to use helpers like `this.get('jobs').each(fn);` - you'll only be able to use it as `Foo.jobs.each(fn)`.

In order for you to use the attribute as an actual collection, you'll have to do a lot more complicated things.

```
var Foo = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    initialize:function(){
      this.createJobs(this.attributes.jobs);
    },
    toJSON: function () {
        var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.apply(this);
        json.jobs = this.get('jobs').toJSON();
        return json;
    },
    set: function (key, val) {
        var attributes;
        if(!_.isObject(key)) {
            attributes = {}; attributes[key] = val;
        } else {
            attributes = key;
        }
        safeAttributes = _.omit(attributes, 'jobs');
        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, safeAttributes);
        if(attributes.jobs) { this.get('jobs').reset(attributes.jobs); }
    },
    clear: function () {
        if(this.get('jobs') && this.get('jobs').destroy) {
            this.get('jobs').off(); 
            this.get('jobs').destroy(); 
        }
        Backbone.Model.prototype.clear.apply(this);
        this.createJobs();
    },
    createJobs: function (jobsArray) {
        var jobsCollection = new Jobs(jobsArray);
        jobsCollection.on('change', function () {this.trigger('change'); }, this);
        this.set('jobs', jobsCollection);
    }
});
```

Note that this is completely untested, but hopefully it shows some of the way you'd do this.

Comment: I ended up by converting the array into BackboneCollection each element apiece in `this.on('reset')` handle.